# "De l'autre côté"

Tags: sens, expressions

"On the other side" seems to be translated as "de l'autre côté."

- [De l'autre côté de ce mur, c'est chez les voisins.](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/51255261/De-l-autre-c%C3%B4t%C3%A9-de-ce-mur-c-est-chez-les-voisins)
- [Sait-on ce qu'il y a de l'autre côté de ce mur ?"](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/51670241/Sait-on-ce-qu-il-y-a-de-l-autre-c%C3%B4t%C3%A9-de-ce-mur)

Questions:

1. Am I correct in understanding that "Je suis de l'autre côté" could mean both "I am **on** the other side [and still am]" and "I am **from** the other side [but am now here]"?
2. Moreover, there does not seem to be any distinction regarding going **to** the other side or **from** the other side. For instance, it seems "Je vais **de** l'autre côté" can mean either "I go **to** the other side" or "I go **from** the other side."
3. After searching on Google and Linguee, it seems that "à l'autre côté" is not used at all.

Is my above understanding correct? Any verification and additional commentary would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 1 the first translation seems correct to me. However I would translate the second sentence “I am from the other side” as Je viens de l’autre côté. 2 the verb “venir” clarifies the difference between to and from

Comment: I would only translate "I am from the other side" by *je viens de l'autre côté* in the context you give in 1. *Je vais de l'autre côté" **only** means "I go to the other side". *À l'autre côté" does sound weird indeed, can't think of a context in which it would be used

Comment: @None D'accord, I see that "aller" has a sense of "going [away]," so "Je vais de l'autre côté" should be "to" and not "from." What if the verb  was "passer" instead? "Je passe de l'autre côté." Is it the same thing ("to the other side" and not "from the other side")? So the notion of "from" in English can only be created using "venir" in this context?

Comment: *Je passe de l'autre côté*.  Maybe I'd add "over" to render *passer* : "I go (am going) over the other side". Yes, you've got it,  *de* goes with *venir* (*aller à* & *venir de*. Just like in English it's "go to" and "come from".

Comment: @None Thank you. So it seems "aller de l'autre côté" is an isolated exception to the general "aller à" construction?

Comment: I see *de l'autre côté* as a unit here rather than being attached to the verb. But could be wrong. Missed a word before. Meant to write: "go over **to** the other side"

Comment: « À l'autre côté » sera possible avec une comparaison nécessitant le *à* : Ce mur est en diagonale *par rapport **à** l'autre côté* de la pièce »

Comment: Note: the present simple in French is often the continuous in English. Je vais de l'autre côté would be "I'm going to the other side". **You are right about 1)**. It *could be either*. "Je suis de l'autre côté [de la frontière]", = come from. though, that would be usually be said Je viens de etc. as None has already said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*De l'autre côté* must be seen as unit/a phrase consisting of a preposition (*de*) + a noun phrase (*l'autre côté*). I would call it a [*syntagme prépositionnel*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/syntagme_pr%C3%A9positionnel) where *de* does not indicate the origin in space.

You cannot have two prepositions following one another<sup>1</sup> and since *de l'autre côté* is a unit and  cannot be broken down, no other preposition is used.

Since in "*de l'autre côté*" *de* does not indicate the origin in space the verb on its own carries the position or the direction: *je suis/je vais/je viens...de l'autre côté*.

This is by far not an exception where *aller* is not followed by *à* when followed by a complement of place, it is always the case when the complement of place is introduced by a preposition: *aller en haut*, *aller sur la lune, aller dans les bois, aller sous l'eau...*

<sup><sup>1</sup>Whereas in English this is possible, e.g. "get onto to the other side"</sup>

Comment: 1. Are the prepositions in your last paragraph (en haut, sur la lune, etc.) also syntagmes prépositionnels? 2. Do you have any other examples of "de" as a syntagme prépositionnel where it does not indicate the origin in space?

Comment: @angryavian I'm not a grammarian and I'm not sure I can distinguish a *syntagme prépositionnel* from a *locution prépositive* or *locution adverbiale*, all I can observe is they interact in the same way with rest of the sentence in the way they form a semantic unit.  Off my head with *aller* and *de*  I can think of *aller de l'avant*. *sur la lune *dans les bois*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 0):

In the context that is considered in the query, "côté" has the particular meaning of surface, space, or part; in the spoken language it takes on often a conventional meaning that depends on the context; for instance, in the context of two contiguous bedrooms "de l'autre côté" may mean "in the other bedroom".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c%C3%B4t%C3%A9)) a) [En parlant d'une partie de l'espace située de part ou d'autre d'une ligne concrète ou idéale qui partage un domaine] Partie.
> (Quasi-)synonyme direction, espace, région.

1/ No,  in a plain literal context, it is not correct;

- Je suis de l'autre côté.
  *I am on the other side*
  *(This is applicable to the plain literal sense of being, that is, when "to be" applies to position. Of course, when you say that, you don't have to occupy the spot you are talking about.*)

*ex.:* — Tu es dans la rangée de droite en classe ?
— Non, je suis de l'autre côté.

- I am from the other side. (*This is applicable, for instance to someone's place of belonging if there is a notion of clear division; in French, you would not say "je suis de l'autre côté" to means that you belong there.* )

*ex.:* — Vous avez donc résidé toute votre vie au sud de la Loire …
— Non, je **vis** de l'autre côté, à Angers. (*No, I am from the other side, from Angers.*)
*or* — Non, je suis du **côté nord de la Loire**, je suis d'Angers.

Possibly, there are cases when the "from" rendering is proper, but I know of none.

2/ There is no distinction on one condition: you must add a complement: "**de** l'autre côté **à** qqc".

- Je vais **de** l'autre côté quand il fait froid. (*This means always that the person goes to the other side*)
- Je vais **de** l'autre côté **au** côté le plus éloigné. (*Not the usual context of "two sides". The motion is from this side that is called "other side" to yet another side. However, there is not much of a case for this type of usage because "de l'autre côté" is  used almost exclusively to provide an "easy" term for the seconde part of a group of two locations that are next to one another and are similar in some way (livingroom/parlour, shop/storage room, vegetable garden/flower garden, …*)

3/ "Vais à l'autre côté", "va à l'autre côté", "vont à l'autre côté", "allé à l'autre côté", "aller à l'autre côté" are not used ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vais+%C3%A0+l%27autre+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%2Cva+%C3%A0+l%27autre+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%2Cvont+%C3%A0+l%27autre+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%2Call%C3%A9+%C3%A0+l%27autre+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%2Caller+%C3%A0+l%27autre+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caller%20%C3%A0%20l%27%20autre%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caller%20%C3%A0%20l%27%20autre%20c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)); the examples corresponding to "aller à l'autre côté" are false positives. This shows that the verb "aller" is not used with "à l'autre côté".

Do not conclude, however, that "à l'autre côté" is never meaningful, though.

- Il faut fixer cette pièce *à l'autre côté*, pas celui-ci. (*"…côté du support de la machine", par exemple; "côté" is more likely to be something line-like in the present example, but in other cases it does not have to be, it can still be a surface or a space*.)

Comment: *Je vais de l'autre côté au côté le plus éloigné* est contradictoire, *Autre côté* implique qu'il n'y a que deux côtés mais le *côté le plus éloigné* serait un troisième côté.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, il n'y a pas de contradiction, mais comme je le dis, les contextes de cette sorte sont rares ;  (une parcelle à six côtés, des arpenteurs, un choix entre deux côtés, rectification, non pas ce côté,  de l'autre, et au côté le plus éloigné de celui-ci)

Comment: Je vois ce que tu veux dire, *yet another side*. Introduire un troisième côté alors qu'on traite une expression qui implique qu'il n'y en a que deux n'est à mon avis pas une bonne idée pour expliquer ladite expression.

Comment: côté ne veut pas dire "surface, space or part". côté veut dire **side**.  L'autre côté de la medaille: the other *side* of the coin. Idioms.

Comment: @Lambie Basically, that is absolutely right. However, in the construction "de l'autre côté", if that remains fundamentally true, because of the way people use that expression, the word "côté" sometimes takes on meaning that is kin to those ideas (space, surface, …). ex. : "Je fais ma couture dans la salle de séjour, mais si le soleil brille je vais la faire de l'autre côté, pour profiter du soleil." . There is nothing that you can really call a side in that case; what is meant is "another room next to the living room", a drawing room, for instance. (1/2)

Comment: @Lambie Did you read the dictionary definition? (2/2)

Comment: The main meaning in the question is side. And especially, for the OP's question. De côté de chez Swann, Swann's Way. So, yes, it can mean a bunch of things. In your example, de  l'autre côté **can mean** the other side of the house. Unless of course, you mean: dans la pièce à côté, in which case, it's the next room or the adjacent room. Next?

Comment: But this: "In the context that is considered in the query, "côté" has the particular meaning of surface, space, or part;" is most definitely misleading in English.

Comment: @Lambie The main meaning is "side", yes, but in the present case I believe that the definition that applies is this one, which you consistently ignore for some reason: "a) [En parlant d'une partie de l'espace située de part ou d'autre d'une ligne concr. ou idéale qui partage un domaine] Partie. (Quasi-)synon. direction, espace, région. (TLFi)". // It is not one query, it is three.

Comment: @Lambie The title ***Du** côté de chez Swann* has been inaccurately but astutely translated to the ambiguous "Swann's Way".  Whatever the meaning of "way" we chose, I don't think the English title can translate back to *Du côté de*.

Comment: @jlliagre "astute but inaccurate translation" is a contradiction in terms. I gave it as an example of an outlier, here a literary one. Literary translations cannot be "backtranslated" and translation does not imply one-to-one equivalence.

Comment: @Lambie Not a contradiction at all. Astute because it gives something that works well in English, inaccurate because the meaning is not the same (*falso ma ben trovato*). You took *Swann's Way* as an example of the multiple meanings of *côté* but *côté* doesn't mean "way" in that title, that's my point.

Comment: You can't possibly think that I think côté means way in a dictionary sense? But allow me to explain the English to you.. The meaning is the same: Swann's Way = over by Swann's house.  over by him, over his way. Where his way means by his house. Du côte de chez nous, on ne trouve aucun lapin. Translation: **Over our way**, there are no rabbits. Our way in English can mean: near our house. So, côté, not in the title would mean: over his way. where way stands for house.

Comment: @Lambie https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_chez_Swann#Le_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_M%C3%A9s%C3%A9glise_ou_de_chez_Swann_et_le_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_Guermantes

Comment: @LPO Merci. Et je n'ai même pas aborder les sens métaphoriques du titre en français. En tout cas, la traduction en anglais du titre est excellente. Proust, there is only one. "Don't forget to send that article my way". clue: not chez moi. But could be.

Comment: Granted, thanks! I learned something: "quand je vous le disais, qu’ils seraient
allés du côté de Guermantes !" → *didn't I tell you that they must have gone the Guermantes way?*

Comment: @Lambie Une [critique du livre](https://www.thesatirist.com/books/fiction-books/swannsway.html) l'a pourtant compris comme moi ( way= voie, route) : *Perhaps “Swann’s Way” means the way of desire as much as it means the route by which young Marcel would take his summer walks.*

Comment: @jlliagre Never mind. I am wasting my time. I really do not care what that book review says. I explained it so well, and you still refuse to understand. Du cóté de chez moi est l'endroit oú il fait ses promenades. Over my way is the place he takes his walks. Where way means **near my house**, not route or path. Even though there would have to be a path. That is why the title is so brilliant in English. Yes, the Guermantes way, by the Guermantes house or place.

Comment: @Lambie Comment ça je refuse de le comprendre ?? Je t'ai même remerciée !

Comment: @Lambie [The Satirist](https://www.thesatirist.com/books/fiction-books/swannsway.html):  "Perhaps “Swann’s Way” means the way of desire as much as it means the route by which young Marcel would take his summer walks.", "'…that the greatest love I have ever known has been for a woman who did not please me, who was not in my style.' Proust has effectively demonstrated the capricious nature of love and infatuation.". "As much 'behaviour' as 'road', perhaps" is the conclusion in that source. The "house metonymy" comes down to "behaviour". In support:  (1/2)

Comment: @Lambie (SOED) **way** **7a** Direction of motion, **relative position**, Freq; preceded by a demonstrative, possessive, or pronominal adj. as _my, this, that, which, etc. or (_colloq._) by place name indicating the place or its neighbourhood **7b** Direction of thought, situation, opinion, etc. Freq. preceded by _this_ or _that_. "Swann's way" where "Swann's" would be a place seems less likely for the reason that usage is  colloquial. However, "**7a**" is perfect. (2/2)

Comment: As interesting as it is, this conversation is getting a bit extended. In case it goes on, I [created a chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130759/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-de-lautre-cote).